# Fetch as Google - Status partial

Tags: google-maps, robots.txt, google-search-console, googlebot

I used google webmaster tool to "Fetch as Google", but I receive the response "partial" because some resources are blocked.
when I check the result, I can read that Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. I have a list with all the files, the priority high are all the images form google maps.
as you can see in this screenshot https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/12opwvUd.png
is there a method to avoid this?

my robots.txt is very basic, so I don't think is a problem of my robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /sass/
```

any suggestion or advice?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it.

Google Maps server is blocking these requests. Not your server. You can see this by looking at the Google Maps robots.txt:
https://maps.googleapis.com/robots.txt

Guessing Google doesn't think the maps data is an important part of your page and worth indexing. And it probably wastes a lot of time crawling Google maps loaded on other sites.

So it's normal and won't stop Google indexing **your** content from your site.

It would be nice if Fetch As Google explained this better - especially as both products are from Google! But on other hand why should it get preferential treatment over other sites that provide resources but don't want to be crawled.